# Black screen with logon text after installing Steam

Tags: steam

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and dual-booted it with Windows 10. I updated to 22.04.2 LTS this morning and installed Steam after rebooting. I waited for it to install, and decided to shut down after installing it because I had to do something else. After booting all I get now is "Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 'pc name' tty2 'pc name' login:" putting in my username and password I get "Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS" How would I fix this issue? It was fine after updating but has started this issue after installing Steam.